# Android scrollview in service

Tags: android, service, scrollview

guys!
I created full-screen scrollview with editText in service using windowManager

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="50dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/service_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/header"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:minHeight="100dp">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText"
                    android:width="20dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But when i input text in EditText keyboard close it, and content doesn't scroll up...
What's wrong with it? Thanx!